# Series Convergence in Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(e_j)_1^\infty$ be an orthonormal set in $l^2$

Consider $$s_n =\sum_{j=1}^n t_je_j$$

Show that $s_n$ converges in $l^2 \iff t = (t_j)_{j=1}^\infty \in l^2$

Thoughts so far :

If we consider $T : F \rightarrow l^2$ where $F \subset l^2$ is the space of sequences with Finite Support. $$ T(x) = \sum x_ne_n \:\: \forall x \in F$$
Then it's easy to show that $T$ is an Isometry and since $F$ is dense in $l^2$ ,  $T$ extends to an Isometry $$T_o : l^2 \rightarrow l^2 $$
$$ T_o(y) = \lim_n T(y_n) \: \: \text{where} \: \: y_n \in F \: \forall n, \: \: \lim_ny_n \rightarrow y$$

I'd like to claim that $s_n$ converges to $T_o(t)$ but I'm sort of stuck on how to proceed.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: for any n: $v_{n}=\left(  t_{1},...,t_{n}\right)  \in F$ and $T\left(
v_{n}\right)  =s_{n}$ right? so $s_{n}=T\left(  v_{n}\right)  =T_{0}\left(
v_{n}\right)  \rightarrow T_{0}\left(  t\right)  ?$

Comment: I think you just need to use the definition to prove the statement using the fact that the Cauchy sequence in a Banach space converges!